# How to use Flow with async/await, promises and thenables?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Flow can do clever stuff like [this](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAsiMEMxQLxQOoQQa0WAPAHYCuAtgEYQBOANFAM7BUCWhA5gHwBQXAxgPaFGUfuQBWALljwkqKIQgB3DFlxIAFAEoA3D1FiAdPQjB1ARgBMAZjoBycgiq2dUAPSuR2PeKMn1twn5gWzsHJxd3KAAzABt+ZWoqfioAQi4gA):

```
type MyMap = WeakMap<number, string>;
const obj: MyMap = new WeakMap();
obj.set(123, 'bar'); // ok
obj.set('not', 'bar'); // flow error!
```

But what about promises, thenables, and async/await?

I was hoping it might be possible to do this kind of thing:

```
type AsyncMultiplier = (number) => Thenable<number>;

const myTransform: AsyncMultiplier = async input => input * 2;

(async () => {
  (await myTransform(2)) * 5; // should be ok

  // forgetting to await the result:
  myTransform(2) * 5; // should give a type error
})();
```

Is there some way to get Flow to understand the semantics of `await`, thenables, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flow understands `async`/`await` and `Promise`s. There is no built-in type for `Thenable` though you may be able to define your own.

Anyway, in your example just replace `Thenable` with `Promise` and you get the expected error. Note that if you try to typecheck your example you get the following error:

```
1: type AsyncMultiplier = (number) => Thenable<number>;
                                      ^ identifier `Thenable`. Could not resolve name
```